# blob files are empty when downloaded from mysql using php

Tags: php

I am new to php. Written some php code to upload, view and download from mysql db. Everything is working well except download. When downloading a file, its downloaded but empty when opened. I am uploading and downloading directly from db. No local files in filesystem. Please help.

**Upload code :**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        if ($_FILES['upload_file1']['size'] <= 0) {
            echo 'Hey, Please choose at least one file';
        } else {
            foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
                if (0 < $value['error']) {
                    echo 'Error during file upload ' . $value['error'];
                } else if (!empty($value['name'])) {
                    $dbConn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'files') or die('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysqli_connect_error());
                    
                    $sql = "insert into files_data(name, type, size, content, saved_date) values('".$value['name']."', '".$value['type']."', '".filesize_formatted($value['size'])."', '".mysqli_escape_string($dbConn, file_get_contents($value['tmp_name']))."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
                    
                    $result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConn));
                    
                    if($result) {
                        echo 'File successfully saved to database';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function filesize_formatted($size) {
        $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
        $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
        
        return number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . ' ' . $units[$power];
    }
    ?>
```

**SQL code:**

```
CREATE TABLE `files_data` (
  `id` int unsigned COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` blob NOT NULL,
  `saved_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**fetching code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>PDF</th>
            </tr>
            <?php  
                include 'dbconfig.php';
                $query = "SELECT * FROM files_data ORDER BY id DESC";  
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
                $row = mysqli_num_rows($result) ;
                for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++){
                    $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $fileName = $arr['name'];
                    $fileContent = $arr['content'];
                ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="download.php?file=<?php echo $arr['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fileName; ?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php   } ?>

        </table>
```

**Download code:**

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf-8');
$id = $_GET['file'];
$query = "SELECT * " ."FROM files_data WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) 
       or die('Error, query failed');
list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
mysqli_close($connection);
exit;

?>
```

**DB table:**

[image]

Comment: Are those backticks on the lines below mysqli_set_charset and above ob_clean there in the actual code? If so, you should be seeing a syntax error in your logs. Either way, have you checked those logs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: This looks like production code .. You really need to consider [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: No the backticks are not in the actual code . I mentioned them manually.

Comment: @Zak I dont have knowledge about prepared statements

Comment: Then now is the right time to learn, before you get hacked. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: You inserted the data using `insert into files_data(name, type, size, content, saved_date)` - is that the actual order of columns in your table? If so, then I doubt that `list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) = ...` with the result of your `SELECT *` query actually reads the values of the _correct_ columns into those variables.

Comment: Yes, The order is correct.

Comment: Can anyone provide any working php code to upload and download blob files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem was with the db. We need to set the table field "content" **type** to **longblob** or the file will get corrupted during upload as it is larger in size and will not fully upload.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sending size in the header that is only some part of the file content is actually disposition in the file and that is why you are getting a corrupted file after downloading.

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf-8');
$id = $_GET['file'];
$query = "SELECT * " ."FROM files_data WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) 
       or die('Error, query failed');
list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
mysqli_close($connection);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Still showing error after download.

Comment: I have also tried with a image. After download and opening the image its displaying half of it. And pdf files are displaying error saying failed to load pdf content.

Comment: Do I need to make any other changes ?

Answer (score 1):

in my local env. where I set this code up. I used LongBlob. So that entire file even if it is large, then also it can save without any issue.